# Limitations of C# to native interop

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke, native

I know that C# allows interoperability with native code using PInvoke ([An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx))

We are planning to develop new code, and are considering 2 options:

1. Native solution + managed (C#) wrapper around interop code that calls the native code.
2. Fully managed solution

I would like to know whether there are any documented limitations to this interop ? (e.g - certain types that cannot be marshalled back and forth between managed/native, etc)

These limitations can affect our decision to use (or not use) option #1.

Comment: What is a *native solution* in your context? If you can do it with managed code why are you considering an alternative?

Comment: I may take the native low-level layer and use it in some other platform that is native only, for example.

Comment: Assuming that you can deploy such a solution, there are no limitations to option 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P.O.D. (plain-old-data) structs are generally fairly easy to marshal.

But if you want to marshal complex C++ classes that contain things like vectors, then you'll run into trouble.

If you can write C/C++ code to transform complex classes into simpler types for calling via p/invoke then that's ok - but otherwise, run away from complex C++ classes.

However, there is another possibility.

You can use the so-called "It just works" technology to wrap C++ code using a *CLI* C++ class. You can mix unmanaged and CLI code in C++ - even in the same file - which can really help.

See here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173185.aspx

http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/03/mcppp2.html (this is rather old)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651516/Exposing-native-to-managed-Cplusplus-CLI-vs-P-Invo

Comment: It may be also possible that the low-level C++ code will be out of my hands (e.g: using an existing library). This can make it harder to force these native structs to be "marshal friendly"

Comment: @lysergic-acid You may be able to wrap the lower level structs in managed C++ classes, and use those from C#.

Comment: @lysergic-acid You can always wrap any library and call it from p/invoke or mixed mode C++/CLI

Comment: @MatthewWatson It is not called managed C++. Its official name is C++/CLI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True - Managed C++ was deprecated ages ago.

Comment: What has C++ got to do with the original OP question of using C#? Just curious

Comment: ps. I have the same problem as what OP said, but only using C#. The problem for me is how to give access to the interop DLL across multiple users logged on at the same time. Currently the application drops out with "object undefined" errors because one person has locked the DLL, whilst the other has not. The later person is getting the error.

Comment: @Fandango68 Because C++/CLI can call unmanaged C++ code directly, and C# can call C++/CLI code directly, which gives you a route to (indirectly) call unmanaged C++ code from C# code.